# How to throttle callback of jQuery event?

Tags: jquery

Ok, so I do search like in google, you type text in input and it gives you entries instantly. But I don't like that. I use something like that `$("TEXTINPUT").keyup(function() {`. When the user types very fast, it connects to database many times. Is it possible, that we would connect to PHP file only when user stops typing for 1-2 seconds, but not instantly? I need to do that in jQuery. Thanks.

Comment: use `setTimeout` with `keyup` fucntion

Comment: I can understand PHP tag here but mysql?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try :

```
var time_out;
$("TEXTINPUT").keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(time_out);
    time_out = setTimeout(your_function, 500);
}

function your_function()
{
    /*CHECK DATABASE*/
}
```

Answer (score 13):

If you use the [Underscore Library](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) it's as simple as this:

`$("TEXTINPUT").keyup(_.throttle(function () {...}, 150));`

Docs from the Underscore site:

> **throttle**   _.throttle(function, wait)
>
> Returns a throttled version of the function, that, when invoked
>   repeatedly, will only actually call the wrapped function at most once
>   per every wait milliseconds. Useful for rate-limiting events that
>   occur faster than you can keep up with.

There is also the [`debounce`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#debounce) function:

> **debounce**   _.debounce(function, wait)
>
> Calling a debounced function will postpone its execution until after wait
>   milliseconds have elapsed since the last time the function was
>   invoked. Useful for implementing behavior that should only happen
>   after the input has stopped arriving. For example: rendering a preview
>   of a Markdown comment, recalculating a layout after the window has
>   stopped being resized...

Comment: There's only one problem: what if you *just* need to throttle a callback? No one needs a library to do this—just a basic understanding of javascript in the browser.

Answer (score 4):

This function will act somewhat like underscore.js, but without the extra dependency. It'll also pass the scope and arguments it's called with to the wrapped function. Unlike YoannM's answer, this returns a self-contained callback that uses no external variables (EG, use as many times as you want).

```
function throttle (func, wait) {
    return function() {
        var that = this,
            args = [].slice(arguments);

        clearTimeout(func._throttleTimeout);

        func._throttleTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            func.apply(that, args);
        }, wait);
    };
}
```

And usage would be nearly identical to that of the underscore.js library.

```
$('input').on('input keyup', throttle(function() {
    // ...
}, 100));
```

Comment: I think this is debouncing, not throttling behaviour

Comment: That's a good point; I wasn't very clear on debounce vs throttle distinctions when I answered the question. The irony of it is, that was an adaptation of underscore's "throttle" function. @ХристоПанайотов perhaps you could clarify: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991367/difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing-a-function (No particularly good answer there.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I usually approach it:

```
$(function(){
  var tiTO, jqXHR;
  $('textinput').keyup(function(){
    if (tiTO) clearTimeout(tiTO);
    if (jqXHR && jqXHR.abort) jqXHR.abort();
    tiTO = setTimeout(function(){
      jqXHR = $.ajax({....});
      //Ajax call to PHP
    },2000);
  });
});
```

Each keyup resets the timeout, and aborts any active ajax.