# Difference between throttling and debouncing a function

Tags: javascript, throttling, debouncing

Can anyone give me an in-simple-words explanation about the difference between throttling and debouncing a function for rate-limiting purposes?

To me, both seem to do the same the thing. I have checked these two blogs to find out, but I'm still having trouble understanding.

http://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: [This](https://web.archive.org/web/20180324022838/http://demo.nimius.net/debounce_throttle/) is a good visualization

Comment: Very simple example that helped me to understand.
https://jsfiddle.net/Voronar/sxjy25ew/1/

Comment: Can see the visualization here as well https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/vOZNQV

Comment: For simple and plain JS implementations of throttle and bounce, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51493084/2202732) on [Simple throttle in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078285/simple-throttle-in-js).

Comment: I'm not a fan of linking to personal websites, as history has shown that most of them will go offline some day. Therefore, I have recorded the debounce demo from nimus so that if it's gone in the future, people still can see it here: https://imgur.com/PkwDnfy

Comment: @thriqon: There is almost no need to read other answers after seeing this visualization. Thanks.

Answer (score 673):

To put it in simple terms:

- **Throttling** will delay executing a function. It will reduce the notifications of an event that fires multiple times.
- **Debouncing** will bunch a series of sequential calls to a function into a single call to that function. It ensures that one notification is made for an event that fires multiple times.

You can visually see the difference [in this demo](https://web.archive.org/web/20220117092326/http://demo.nimius.net/debounce_throttle/), which shows when a debounced vs throttled event would fire based on mouse movement.

If you have a function that gets called a lot - for example when a resize or mouse move event occurs, it can be called a lot of times. If you don't want this behaviour, you can **Throttle** it so that the function is called at regular intervals. **Debouncing** will mean it is called at the end (or start) of a bunch of events.

Comment: I think thriqon's visualization link shows how it works very well. If you have a function that gets called a lot - for example when a resize or mouse move event occurs, it can be called a lot of times. If you don't want this, you can throttle it so that the function is called at regular intervals. Debouncing will mean it is called at the end (or start) of a bunch of calls.

Comment: So isn debouncing just throttle with longer delay?

Comment: with debouncing you are delaying the execution - for example with a mouse move - you don't want the function to execute for every pixel of movement - rather you want to execute it at the end of the mouse movement.

Comment: @AdamM. Have a look at the visualization [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180324022838/http://demo.nimius.net/debounce_throttle/)

Comment: You started with.. *"Throttling will delay executing a function."*  and in the end you are saying *"With debouncing you are delaying the execution"*... I thought we were talking about the differences..?

Comment: @AdamM. No. You can visualize this by moving your mouse in the [demo](http://demo.nimius.net/debounce_throttle/), and stopping mouse movement every once in a while. The debounce-bar will "tick" _after_ you stopped all mouse movement, while the throttle-bar will keep "ticking" _while_ the mouse is moving, but at a reduced (throttled) rate.

Comment: I prefer leading debounce than trailing debounce. Executes the call right away, and blocks subsequent calls.

Comment: @Donal thank you for providing link. your text does not exactly reflect the actual behavior

Comment: @WadihM. Block for how long? Probably what you mean is actually a throttle.

Comment: @trollkotze Hey! I checked again, the one I was referring to is "leading edge debounce", or "immediate debounce", I remember at the time when I used that function that was my favorite because it would fire right away so it was closely correlated to the first raw event. https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/#leading-edge-or-immediate. For the block for how long, I meant the "wait" parameter which can be set for the debounce that will be used for the setInterval timer.

Comment: The link to the visualization is dead. Here is a Wayback Machine version: https://web.archive.org/web/20220117092326/http://demo.nimius.net/debounce_throttle/.

Answer (score 238):

Personally I found **debounce** harder to comprehend than **throttle**.

As both functions help you postpone and reduce the rate of some execution. Assuming you are calling decorated functions returned by throttle/debounce repeatedly...

- **Throttle**: the original function will be called at most once per specified period.
- **Debounce**: the original function will be called after *the caller stops calling the decorated function after a specified period*.

I found the last part of debounce crucial to understand the goal it's trying to achieve. I also found an old version of the implementation of _.debounce helps the understanding (courtesy of https://davidwalsh.name/function-debounce).

```
// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
_.debounce = function(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
        timeout = null;
        if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};
```

A far-fetched metaphor, but maybe could also help.

You have a friend named Chatty who likes to talk with you via IM. Assuming when she talks she sends a new message every 5 seconds, while your IM application icon is bouncing up and down, you can take the...

- *Naive* approach: check every message as long as it arrives. When your app icon bounces, check. It's not the most effective way, but you are always up-to-date.
- *Throttle* approach: you check once every 5 minutes (when there are new ones). When new message arrives, if you have checked anytime in the last 5 minutes, ignore it. You save your time with this approach, while still in the loop.
- *Debounce* approach: you know Chatty, she breaks down a whole story into pieces, sends them in one message after another. You wait until Chatty finishes the whole story: if she stops sending messages for 5 minutes, you would assume she has finished, now you check all.

Answer (score 221):

#### Differences

|  | Throttle 1 sec. | Debounce 1 sec. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Delay | No delay | 1 second delay |
| Emits new if... | 1 second has passed since the last output | After the last input, the following 1 sec has no new input |

#### Explanation by use case

- **Search bar**: Don't want to search every time the user presses a key? Want instead to search after the user stopped typing for 1 second? Use `debounce` 1 second on key press.
- **Shooting game**: Pistol takes 1 second of time between each shot, but the user clicks the mouse multiple times within 1 second. Using `throttle` on mouse click ensures the clicks that are too early are ignored.

##### Reversing their roles

- **Throttling 1 second on the search bar**: If a user types "abcdefghij", with each subsequent character getting typed every 0.6 seconds, then `throttle` will trigger at the first "a" press. It will then ignore every press for next 1 second; i.e. "b" at the 0.6 second mark will be ignored. Then "c" at 1.2 seconds will again trigger a search, which then resets the time again, and so on for subsequent keys (e.g. "d" at 1.8 seconds will be ignored, but "e" at 2.4 will fire, etc.).
- **Debouncing the pistol for 1 second**: When a user sees an enemy, he clicks the mouse, but it will not shoot. He will click again several times in that second but it still will not shoot. Only after ceasing his clicks for a full second will the pistol finally fire, one single shot.

#### A "real life" comparison

There are some guards outside a bar. Guards allow a person who says "I want to go in" inside the bar. This is a normal scenario. Anyone saying "I want to go in" is allowed to go inside the bar.

Now there is a **Throttle Guard** (*throttle 5 seconds*). He likes people who respond first. Anyone who says "I will go" first, he allows that person inside. Then he rejects every person for the next *5 seconds*. After that, again anyone saying it first will be allowed and others will be rejected for the next *5 seconds*.

There is another guard, the **Debounce Guard** (*debounce 5 seconds*). He likes people who bring mental rest to him for *5 seconds*. So if any person says "I will go", the guard waits for *5 seconds*. If no other person disturbs him in those 5 seconds, he allows the first person inside. But, if some other person interrupts and says "I will go" in those *5 seconds*, he will reject the first one, and again start the *5 seconds* of waiting, this time for the second person. If 5 seconds pass without interruption now, that *second* person will be let in, but not the first.

Comment: Very clear explanation!

Comment: What if two people come, the second 1s after the other. Shouldn't the throttle gard let the second person come 4s after he arrived? (to not lose that person in the end)

Comment: @Rivenfall Throttle and Debounce are designed to reduce the noise, so they are designed to lose some persons. They have different strategy to lose persons. What you are looking for is the delay operator [https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/delay]. It will just delay their responses. The Delay Gaurd will be the normal guard, just that for him processing of voices takes 5 sec.  So will allow all but after a 5 sec delay.

Comment: In the end I used a date difference delta = now - last update. setTimeout with delay - delta when delta < delay. So it takes the first event immediately and doesn't ignore the last one.

Comment: I got your query wrong. You were telling a different use case.

Comment: This is not quite right. Debouncing can be done with or without a delay. If you debounce your function directly, there's a delay. To debounce a function without a delay, write *If `flag` is true, run my function, then set `flag` to false*, and then debounce a statement setting the flag back to true. Perhaps there's a word for this other than "debouncing"?

Comment: In my opinion, this should be most upvoted.

Comment: This answer is not correct - the table is confusing. According to the table, if event appears and last emit was in < 1 sec, then `throllete` will drop it. It's not true.

Answer (score 112):

**Throttle (1 sec):** Hello, I am a robot. As long as you keep pinging me, I will keep talking to you, but after exactly 1 second each. If you ping me for a reply before a second is elapsed, I will still reply to you at exactly 1 second interval. In other words, I just love to reply at exact intervals.

**Debounce (1 sec):** Hi, I am that ^^ robot's cousin. As long as you keep pinging me, I am going to remain silent because I like to reply only after 1 second is passed **since the last time you pinged me**. I don't know, if it is because I have an attitude problem or because I just don't like to interrupt people. In other words, if you keep asking me for replies before 1 second is elapsed since your last invocation, you will never get a reply. Yeah yeah...go ahead! call me rude.

---

**Throttle (10 min):** I am a logging machine. I send system logs to our backend server, after a regular interval of 10 minutes.

**Debounce (10 sec):** Hi, I am not cousin of that logging machine. (Not every *debouncer* is related to a *throttler* in this imaginary world). I work as a waiter in a nearby restaurant. I should let you know that as long as you keep adding stuff to your order, I will not go to the kitchen for execution of your order. Only when 10 seconds have elapsed **after you last modified your order**, I will assume that you are done with your order. Only then will I go and execute your order in the kitchen.

---

Cool Demos: https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/

Credits for the waiter analogy: https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf

Comment: And throttle doesn't automatically delay, but only if necessary.

Comment: very well explained. Cleared in a minute

Answer (score 62):

**Throttling** enforces a maximum number of times a function can be called over time. As in "execute this function at most once every 100 milliseconds."

**Debouncing** enforces that a function not be called again until a certain amount of time has passed without it being called. As in "execute this function only if 100 milliseconds have passed without it being called."

[ref](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/)

Answer (score 39):

## It's simpler than the demos.

When **throttle** is being called it fires your function periodically (eg. every 20ms) – and once at the end.

**Debounce** only fires at the end (eg. 20ms after the last event).

So, as long as events continue to fire rapidly (eg. in intervals of less than 20ms), debounce will remain silent, while throttle will fire once every 20ms. Both will fire at the end, the difference is only throttle will also fire in-between at set intervals.

**Example**: If you're scrolling, throttle will slowly call your function while you scroll (every X milliseconds).  Debounce will wait until after you're done scrolling to call your function (possibly only once).

---

*I like to think of throttle as "including debounce", **they both make a final call after the events are done**, but due to implementation details, the two don't always make this final call at the exact same time, making demos confusing.*

Comment: it's worth noting that in these demos, they may not look "identical" because debounce will always fire X milliseconds after the last event, while throttle's last call may happen sooner (and it doesn't need to be called again when debounce would normally fire). it's pretty inconsequential, but worth mentioning if you look at the demos.

Answer (score 31):

In layman's terms:

**Debouncing** will prevent a function from running *while* it is still being called frequently. A debounced function will only run *after* it has been determined that it is no longer being called, at which point it will run exactly once. Practical examples of debouncing:

- *Auto-saving or validating the contents of a text-field if the user "stopped typing": the operation will only be done once, AFTER it has been determined that the user is no longer typing (no longer pressing keys).*
- *Logging where users rest their mouse: the user is no longer moving their mouse, so the (last) position can be logged.*

**Throttling** will simply prevent a function from running if it has run recently, regardless of the call frequency. Practical examples of throttling:

- *Implementations of v-sync are based on throttling: the screen will only be drawn if 16ms elapsed since the last screen draw. No matter how many times the screen refresh functionality is called, it will only run at most once every 16ms.*

Answer (score 28):

A real-life analogy that personally helps me remember:

- **debounce =  a conversation**. you wait for the other person to finish speaking before you reply.
- **throttle = a drum bit**. you only play notes on a simple 4/4 drum bit.

Use cases for *debounce*:

- **Typing.** You want to do something after the user stopped typing. So waiting 1sec after the last keystroke makes sense. Each keystroke restarts the wait.
- **Animation.** You want to shrink back an element after the user stopped hovering over it. Not using debounce might cause an erratic animation as a result of the cursor unintentionally moving between the "hot" and "cold" zones.

Use cases for *throttle*:

- **Scrolling.** You want to react to scrolling but limit the amount of calculations made, so doing something every 100ms is enough to prevent potential lag.
- **Mouse move.** Same as scrolling but for mouse move.
- **API calls** You want to fire an API call on certain UI events but want to limit the number of API calls you make not to overload your server.

Answer (score 26):

#### A picture is worth a thousand words

Throttle
[image: Throttle]

Debounce
[image: Debounce]

Notice the **Debounce** will not fire until the events flow stops. However, **Throttle** will fire an event each interval.

(Thanks to [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/))

Comment: Live code example: https://codepen.io/dcorb/pen/KVxGqN

Comment: I can't imagine how much more words it'd be worth if the raw events matched both on the throttle and debounce images....

Comment: What are we supposed to get from the picture? It shows different raw events so we can't compare the behaviors of the functions...

Answer (score 23):

**Debouncing** allows you to manage the frequency of calls that a function can receives. It combines multiple calls that happen on a given function so that repeated calls that occur before the expiration of a specific time duration are ignored. Basically debouncing ensures that exactly one signal is sent for an event that may be happening several times.

**Throttling** restricts the frequency of calls that a function receives to a fixed time interval. It is used to ensuring that the target function is not invoked more often than the specified delay. Throttling is the reduction in rate of a repeating event.

Answer (score 12):

Putting debounce and throttle together can be very confusing, because they both share a parameter called `delay`.

[image]

**Debounce**. The `delay` is to wait till there's no more invokes anymore, then to invoke it. Very much like to close an elevator door: the door has to wait till no one tries to get in before closing.

**Throttle**. The `delay` is to wait with a frequency, then invokes for the last one. Very much like to fire a pistol gun, the gun just can't be fired beyond certain rate.

---

Let's take a look at the implementation to see in details.

```
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  let handle = null
  
  return function () {
    if (handle) {
      handle = clearTimeout(handle)
    }
    
    handle = setTimeout(() => {
      fn(...arguments)
    }, delay)
  }
}
```

Debounce, keeps interrupting the timeout until no more interruptions, and then fires `fn`.

```
function throttle(fn, delay) {
  let handle = null
  let prevArgs = undefined
  
  return function() {
    prevArgs = arguments
    if (!handle) {
      fn(...prevArgs)
      prevArgs = null
      handle = setInterval(() => {
        if (!prevArgs) {
          handle = clearInterval(handle)
        } else {
          fn(...prevArgs)
          prevArgs = null
        }
      }, delay)
    }
  }
}
```

Throttle, stores the last call arguments, and sets up an interval to fire until no past fires any more.

**Similarities**. They both have a delay time, and there's no fire during the delay, especially when there's only one fire. Both do not aggregate past events, so the number of events can be different than the actual fires.

**Difference**. The delay can be extended in debounce case with repeated events. Whereas the delay in the throttle case is fixed. So in general you get more fires from the throttle than debounce.

**Easy to remember**. Debounce groups bundle calls into one. Throttle keeps bundle calls within certain frequency.

### Updated 1-20-23

Throttle might not need `setInterval`, here's a new version I wrote recently which takes care of `this` as well.

```
function throttle(fn, delay) {
  let canFire = true
  let queue = []

  function pop() {
    if (queue.length < 1) return 

    const [that, args] = queue.pop()
    fn.apply(that, args)
    canFire = false
    setTimeout(() => {
      canFire = true
      pop()
    }, delay)
  }
  
  function push() {
    queue.push([this, arguments])
    if (canFire) pop()
  } 

  push.cancel = () => {
    queue = []
  }

  return push
}
```

### Updated 11-09-23

I start to believe throttle is an add-on on top of debounce. Read this https://windmaomao.medium.com/throttle-is-a-debounce-add-on-80d4a6027ad4.

```
function throttle(fn, delay) {
  let h
  let queue = []

  function pop() {
    if (queue.length < 1) return 

    if (!h) {
      const [that, args] = queue.pop()
      fn.apply(that, args) 
      
      h = setTimeout(() => {
        h = null
        pop()
      }, delay)      
    }      
  }
  
  return function push() {
    queue.push([this, arguments])
    pop()
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**Throttling**

> Throttling enforces a maximum number of times a function can be called
>   overtime. As in "execute this function at most once every 100
>   milliseconds." Say under normal circumstances you would call this
>   function 1,000 times over 10 seconds. If you throttle it to only once
>   per 100 milliseconds, it would only execute that function at most 100
>   times

```
(10s * 1,000) = 10,000ms
10,000ms / 100ms throttling = 100 maximum calls
```

**Debouncing**

> Debouncing enforces that a function not be called again until a
>   certain amount of time has passed without it being called. As in
>   "execute this function only if 100 milliseconds have passed without it
>   being called."

Perhaps a function is called 1,000 times in a quick burst, dispersed over 3 seconds, then stops being called. If you have debounced it at 100 milliseconds, the function will only fire once, at 3.1 seconds, once the burst is over. Each time the function is called during the burst it resets the debouncing timer

source:- [throttle and debouncing](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/)

Answer (score 5):

**throtle** is just a wrapper around **debounce** which makes **debounce** to call passed `function` in some period of time, if **debounce** delays a function call on period of time which is bigger then specified in **throtle**.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose we have a callback function "cb" to be called on event "E".
Let "E" getting triggered 1000 times in 1 second, hence there would be 1000 calls to "cb". That is 1 call/ms. To optimize we can either use:

- **Throttling**: With throttling of (100ms), "cb" would be
  called on [100th ms, 200th ms, 300th ms, ... 1000th ms]. That is 1 call/100 ms. **Here 1000 calls to "cb" optimized to 10 calls.**
- **Debouncing**: With debouncing of (100ms), "cb" would be called only once on [1100th sec]. That is 100ms after the last trigger of "E" which happend on [1000th ms]. **Here 1000 calls to "cb" optimized to 1 call.**

Answer (score 4):

the lodash Library suggests the following article https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/ which detailed explain the difference between `Debounce` and `Throttle` and their origination

Answer (score 4):

**Debouncing** and **Throttling** are ways to select targets from a serial of events for the reduction purpose. Both of them need a period of time as an argument, for example: `x` ms, and `leading` / `tailing` variety to define how to select events.

### Debouncing

Select an event when no other event occurs in next `x` ms

```
"--->": timeline

"o,c,e": events, where 
"o" are events selected by "leading"
"e" are events selected by "tailing"
"c" are skipped events

"|===|": period (x=5)
```

```
--oc-e-----occ-e----o-cc--ce-----o-c-cce------> source events
  |===|    |===|    |===|        |===|
  ||===|   ||===|   | |===|      | |===|   
  |  |===| | |===|  |  |===|     |   |===|
  |      | |   |===||     |===|  |    |===|
  |      | |       ||      |===| |     |===|
--o--------o--------o------------o------------> selected events (leading)
---------e---------e-----------e-----------e--> selected events (tailing)
```

### Throttling

Select an event in every `x` ms when an event occurs

```
--oc-e-----occ-e----o-ce--oe-----o-c-eoe------> source events
  |===|    |===|    |===| |===|  |===||===|
--o--------o--------o-----o------o----o-------> selected events (leading)
------e--------e--------e-----e------e----e---> selected events (tailing)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Debouncing** makes it so a function can only be executed after a certain amount of time since it was last invoked

```
function debounce(func,wait){
  let timeout
  return(...arg) =>{
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout= setTimeout(()=>func.apply(this,arg),wait)
  }
}


function SayHello(){
  console.log("Jesus is saying hello!!")
}


let x = debounce(SayHello,3000)
x()
```

The **throttle** pattern limits the maximum number of times a given event handler can be called over time. It lets the handler be called periodically, at specified intervals, ignoring every call that occurs before this wait period is over.

```
function throttle(callback, interval) {
  let enableCall = true;

  return (...args)=> {
    if (!enableCall) return;

    enableCall = false;
    callback.apply(this, args);
    setTimeout(() => enableCall = true, interval);
  }
}


function helloFromThrottle(){
  console.log("Jesus is saying hi!!!")
}

const foo = throttle(helloFromThrottle,5000)
foo()
```

Comment: Don't use `this` in `callback.apply()` or don't return an arrow function

Answer (score 2):

### How debouncing works in hardware.

Debouncing is the process of removing noise from a digital signal. When a button is pressed, the signal bouncing around can cause the button to be registered as being pressed multiple times. Debouncing removes this noise so that the button is only registered as being pressed once.  Picture a ruler being bounced on the edge of a desk, and imagine metal contacts inside a switch bouncing like this.

[image]

Better still, look at this diagram, showing the switch noise caused by bouncing.

[image]

We use [resistors and capacitors of properly calculated ratings](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/371116/calculating-r-and-c-for-schmitt-trigger-debouncer) to smooth out the signal for *n* ms.

### Explain how signal throttling works in hardware.

Signal throttling is the process of limiting the number of times a signal can be registered. This is often used to prevent a button from being registered as being pressed multiple times in a short period of time.

I prefer the term gating, but that's because I'm into electronic music production.

We open the gate at the end of each throttle period, and allow the signal to pass, and then close the gate again, for the next throttle period.

### Explain how debouncing works in software.

Debouncing in software is often accomplished by using a timer. When the button is pressed, the timer is started. If the button is pressed again before the timer expires, the timer is reset. This ensures that the button can only be registered as being pressed once per debounce period.

In many implementations of debounce, we create a debounced version of the function which is embedded in a closure containing a timer (or gate).  When the timer delay expires we set it it null again.  The actual function only runs when the timer is null.  Usually, this means when we first call the debounced function, it'll run once, then subsequent calls to it will be effectively cancelled until the delay time has elapsed.

In some implementations of debounce, while a stream of calls are fired and the timer hasn't expired, the timer will be restarted.  Only calling the function after the bouncing has stopped.  This is usually called a trailing debounce.

### Explain how throttling works in software.

Throttling in software is often accomplished by using a counter. When the button is pressed, the counter is incremented. If the button is pressed again before the counter reaches a certain threshold, the counter is reset. This limits the number of times the button can be registered as being pressed in a given period of time.  It's good to visualise this as a pulse or beat, which opens and closes a gate while calls are being sent to the throttle.

Rate limiting is another way to think of a throttle.

### Why is this such a common cause of confusion?

In many many use cases a debounce or throttle will get you the results you want, especially if the software implementation you're using allows you to chain, trail, or lead your throttle / debounce.

Still, I hope all the answers here and this one have helped you understand more clearly.

They're very similar.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**Debouncing and Throttling in Javascript**

Both functions help to postpone or limit the rate at which some functions are executed.
This in turn helps in optimising our web apps.

What is a Throttling?

- Throttling is the way in which we trigger the function within the given amount of time.
- The first request is allowed to pass.
- The original function is executed only once per specified time

Example:
The below image depicts the click events which are fired at an interval/delay of 40ms,
The events e2,e3, and e4 occurred within 40ms and hence did not get executed.

[image]

Code for throttling,

```
const trottle = function (fn, d) {
  let flag = true;        // to pass the first event

  return function () {
    if (flag) {
      fn();              // execute the decorative function
      flag = false;      // block the next fired events
      setTimeout(() => {
        flag = true;     // unblock the next fired events after a specified delay
      }, d);
    }
  };
};
```

A throttling function is commonly used in resizing or scrolling events.

What is debouncing?

- Debouncing is a way in which we stop the function from being called if it was called recently.
- Only the last request is allowed to pass.
- The original function is executed only if the caller stops calling the decorated function for the specified amount of time.

Example:
The below image depicts the click events which are fired only after a delay(100ms) is completed,

[image]

Events e1,e2,e3 and e4 were fired by the user but were not successfully executed because the consecutive event occurred within 100ms. (delay between e1 and e2 < 100ms or e2 and e3 < 100ms… etc)
Event e4 successfully calls the decorated function because there is a delay of 100ms after it is fired by the user.
Code for debouncing:

```
const debounce = function (fn, d) {
  let timer;

  return function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);           // clears/reset the timer if the event is triggered withing the delay
    timer = setTimeout(() => {     // execute the function
      fn();
    }, d);
  };
};
```

A debouncing function is commonly used to limit typing(input fields) or clicking events.

Debouncing and Throttling in Action:

[image]

Denouncing vs throttling
You can visually see the difference here

Supporting documents:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-throttling/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/debouncing-in-javascript/

[Difference Between throttling and debouncing a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991367/difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing-a-function)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBIEArmPywU

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, in simple terms
Throttling - similar to calling setInterval(callback) for certain number of times i.e calling same function for certain number of times over time on occurrence of event
 and..
Debouncing - similar to calling setTImeout(callbackForApi) or calling a function after certain time has passed on occurrence of event.
This link can be helpful-
https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/

Answer (score 1):

For examples of typical uses cases, I recommend @Guy's answer. But the best way for me to understand these two concepts was to make it about pizzas.

Let's say you're an amazing pizza-maker, and so customers are in your shop constantly demanding more pizzas.

**Throttling:**
You decide you will only put out one pizza at the end of every hour, as long you received at least one request for pizza during that hour.

You receive 100 requests for pizzas in one hour, so you provide a pizza at the end of that hour. Then, you get no requests for pizza the next hour, so you don't put out a pizza. Then you get 10 requests for pizzas the next hour, and so you put out a pizza at the end of that hour.

**Debouncing:**
You are getting annoyed about your customers constantly demanding pizzas, and so you decide you will only give them a pizza after they have stopped asking you for a full minute.

They demand pizzas for 30 minutes straight, but then they stop asking for a minute after that. At that point, you will give them one pizza.

Then they demand pizzas for 5 minutes straight, and stop asking for a minute after that. At that point, you give them another pizza.

Answer (score 1):

it’s in fact the way of limiting an event. For example, if you are listening on an event onclick, if it’s regular it will listen to every click you made.

If you use Throttle, it will set an interval between the time you want to listen to event for example listen to one click every second.

Debounce is a more restrictive one, it will only fire itself at the beginning or the ending of an event. For example, you are scrolling and you use Debounce, it will trigger only when you start and you finish to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

### Debounce:

Executes the function after the interval if function isn't being called within that interval.

### Throttle:

Executes the function n times at fixed interval.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The major difference between **debouncing** and **throttling** is that debounce calls a function when a user hasn't carried out an event in a specific amount of time, while throttle calls a function at intervals of a specified amount of time while the user is carrying out an event.

Answer (score 0):

This article explains it rather well and has graphics too.

https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/

From the article (and with some clarifications):

> The main difference between this (throttle) and debouncing is that throttle guarantees the execution of the function regularly, at least every X milliseconds.

Normally debounce calls the function at the end of a specified time and throttle calls when the first call to the throttled function is made. Sometimes debounce can take extra config that changes this to do the call at the beginning instead.  Some implemenations of debounce can actually do what throttle does (see Lodash source code) when called with specific configs.

Answer (score 0):

Simple concept for **throttle** is clicking the submit button frequently in a form, we need to use throttle. So the submit function is prevent from frequent clicks. It saves the same requests pass into the function.

And about **debounce**, write a simple code with input text tag for searching some data from the server. oninput, you use the debounce so it removes the previous requests and pass the last typed word to the server

```
const throttle = (callback, time = 0) => {
    let throttle_req, count = 0;
     return async function () {
         var context = this, args = arguments;  
         if(throttle_req) return;  
         throttle_req = true; 
         if(time > 0)
         {
             callback.apply(context, args); 
             setTimeout(() => {
              throttle_req = false; 
             }, time || 200) 
         }
         else
         {
           let response = await callback.apply(context, args); 
            throttle_req = false; 
           return response;
         } 
     }
  }
const debounce = (callback, time = 0) => {
    let debounce_req;
    return function () {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(debounce_req) 
        debounce_req = setTimeout(() => {
             debounce_req = null;
             callback.apply(context, args);
        }, time || 200) 
    }
}
```

How we call: Just wrap your function with **throttle** or **debounce** to check the difference

**Throttle** ex: same button click more than 1 time

```
var throttleFunct = throttle(function(num) {
  console.log(num, "hello throttle")
}, 2000);
throttleFunct(300) //it execute. because its the first call
throttleFunct(400) //it won't execute
```

**throttle async without time**

```
var getDataAsync =  throttle(function(id, name) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {  
      setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({name: name, id: id})
      }, 2000)
     }) 
});
async function test() {
let response = await getDataAsync(120, 'Sherley').then(resp => resp)  
console.log(response, "respond") //it execute. because its the first call
response = await getDataAsync(120, 'James').then(resp => resp)  
console.log(response, "respond2")//it executes 2 after first request
response = await getDataAsync(120, 'Jonathan').then(resp => resp)  
console.log(response, "respond3")//it executes 3 after second request
    }
    test()
```

**Debounce** For ex: search box autocomplete

```
var debounceFunct = debounce(function(num) {
  console.log(num+1)
}, 2000);
debounceFunct(300) //it won't execute and it cancelled
debounceFunct(400) // it executes and it replaced with the previous call. because this is the latest event fire
```

Answer (score 0):

What really matters here, in most simple terms: if you have some action, that is continuously repeated for some period (such as mouse movement, or page resize events), and you need to run some function in response, but you don't want to react to *every* action (cause it may detriment the performance), you have 2 options:

- debounce - you skip all incoming actions, except the last one (the 'last one' is defined by the 'wait' time period you set for debounce function, for example, 2s - it will consider that actions flood stopped, if no actions were taken for 2s, and then it will react. This strategy is reasonable if you don't care about regular updates, you just need to react at least once.
- throttle - if you want to react 'on schedule', to make regular updates even if actions flood is endless, you make your function run at regular intervals (no more often, then the specified time interval), for example 2s throttling will mean that your response will be executed an once if action is taken, but no less then 2s after that. So with continuous actions flood your response will be run on 0s, 2s, 4s, 6s, 8s...