# Throttle & debounce functions

Tags: javascript, function, throttling, debouncing

I am a bit uncertain with the concepts of throttle and debounce functions.

#### As I get it:

**we *debounce*** a function that should be called after a certain event has happened. It is used in events like drag, keyup, etc. with the purpose of not firing all the time the event gets fired but instead when the series of events is done. Typically after a whole word has been typed, or a drag or resize sequence has ended.

**we *throttle*** a function that should fire while a series of events is happening, but when we want to control the amount of times it gets called. Like in a drag movement we want the function to be called only every x pixels of distance, or only every 100ms, and not every time the event is fired. So the throttle function is called while the series of events is happening, just fewer times.

#### Question:

is this a correct perception of what these functions are and their purpose? are there other features that distinguish them?

Comment: [Ben Alman's post on throttle vs debounce has some useful visualizations](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/).

Comment: @zzzzBov interesting reading. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference Between throttling and debouncing a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991367/difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's a good synopsis of the differences.

However, you might want to emphasize that these methods don't actually alter the functions they are called upon. They just create a new function (with an identity, to which the rate limiting behaviour is bound) that can be called as often as necessary, and internally relays the calls to the debounced or throttled function.

Comment: Thank you Bergi. Is there a implicit rule/convention that the scope of the function should be passed into the debounce or throttle function?

Comment: What do you mean by "scope"? The scope of the debounced/throttled is implicitly passed to those functions (but cannot be accessed) as it is bound by closure.

Comment: I mean like [in the underscore debounce function](http://davidwalsh.name/function-debounce), there is a `context` being passed in `.apply(context, arguments)` when the function is finally called. Should one expect that from a debounce function, as a convention/rule?

Comment: No, that's just a convenience parameter (they used `apply` anyway) and not inherent to throttling/debouncing behaviour. You could just as well have to use `.bind()` on the throttled/debounced function, and I'm certain that with ES6 arrow functions we will see such things fewer. But you're right, it's an underscorejs convention that all callback-taking functions also take a `this` context.

Answer (score 4):

For short:

**throttle** is designed to call function in certain interval during constant call.
Like: window.scroll.
**debounce** is designed to call function only once during one certain time. not matter how many time it called.
Like: submit button click.
Here is the example:

```
//http://jsfiddle.net/1dr00xbn/
```

you can see the difference.

Comment: This is very short and very clear to understand.

Answer (score 1):

As my TL pointed out today, It is worth mentioning that in the popular implementation of this 2 functions in lodash:

- https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/debounce.js
- https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/throttle.js

The throttle function is actually just a specific configuration of debounce:

```
function throttle(func, wait, options) {
  let leading = true
  let trailing = true

  if (typeof func != 'function') {
    throw new TypeError('Expected a function')
  }
  if (isObject(options)) {
    leading = 'leading' in options ? !!options.leading : leading
    trailing = 'trailing' in options ? !!options.trailing : trailing
  }
  return debounce(func, wait, {
    'leading': leading,
    'maxWait': wait,
    'trailing': trailing
  })
}
```