# How to invoke a function only once per call stack?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, callstack, throttling

Let's say I have a server that sends data to its clients each time a client's data has changed. The client class looks like this:

```
function Client() {
    this.data = {};
    this.update = function (key, value) {
        this.data[key] = value;
        this.emitUpdate();
    };

    this.emitUpdate = function () {
        // tell server to send this client's data
    };
}

var myClient = new Client();
```

If I change just one thing:

```
myClient.update("name", "John");
```

the server updates all clients with this client's new information. Great.

### But...

If I change multiple things at once from different places in my app:

```
if (something === true) {
    myClient.update("something", true);
} else {
    myClient.update("something_else", true);
}

myClient.update("age", Date.now());
```

there will always be two things changed and `emitUpdate()` will be called twice. The server will send the data twice and all clients will have to render it twice. Imagine 100 changes like that occurring... It would be a big overhead, considering the server could send the update just once, since all of these changes happen in one time frame.

How do I make `emitUpdate()` invoke only once per call stack? I use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#defer) and checked out the `defer()` and `throttle()` functions. Problem is, I need their effects combined.

```
var log = function () {
  console.log("now");
};

// logs "now" 10 times
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  _.defer(log);
}

// logs "now" 10 times
var throttled = _.throttle(log, 0);
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  throttled();
}
```

If I use `throttle()` with a different amount of `wait` like `1` or `2`, the results are inconsistent - sometimes it's called once, sometimes more.

I need something like this:

```
// logs "now" once
var magic = _.deferottle(log);
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  magic();
}
```

Is there a way I could achieve it?

Comment: Why not just separate `emitUpdate` from `update` and call the former as needed?

Comment: Why not debounce on the end of updates to emit a change? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991367/difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing-a-function http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for multiple synchronous calls to the `update()` method:

```js
function Client() {
  this.data = {};
  this.update = function (key, value) {
    this.data[key] = value;
    if (!this.aboutToUpdate) {
      this.aboutToUpdate = setTimeout(() => {
        this.aboutToUpdate = false
        this.emitUpdate()
      })
    }
  };

  this.emitUpdate = function () {
    // tell server to send this client's data
    console.log('update sent', this.data)
  };
}

// This should only log 'update sent' once
var client = new Client()
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  client.update(i, i)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't need `throttle`, just use `defer` in conjunction with some boolean flag check.

Something like this:

```
this.update = function (key, value) {
    this.data[key] = value;
    if (this.isQueued) return;
    this.isQueued = true;
    _.defer(function () {
        this.isQueued = false;
        this.emitUpdate();
    }.bind(this));
};
```

Comment: You realize that this is literally the same as my answer, except with a dependency on underscore and 14 minutes later.

Answer (score 0):

A solution popped in my head while taking a shower:

```js
var deferottle = function(func) {
  var called, args, ctx;

  return function() {
    args = arguments;
    ctx = this;

    if (!called) {
      called = true;
      setTimeout(function() {
        func.apply(ctx, args);
        called = false;
      });
    }
  };
};

var magic = deferottle(function(num) {
  console.log("num: ", num);
});

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  magic(i);
}
```

Turns out [`debounce()`](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) with a wait of `0` can also be used:

```js
var magic = _.debounce(function(num) {
  console.log("num: ", num);
}, 0);

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  magic(i);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This isn't really a solution to your problem since it will only propagate the last call. For example `myClient.update("something_else", true); myClient.update("age", Date.now());` will only update the `age` key.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work for the first part of my answer, but it is a solution to the second part. The implementation of underscore's `debounce()`, is something like my `deferottle()` function, actually. Thanks for pointing this out, though!

Comment: I meant the first part of my _question_. And I have an extra comma.