# Difference between throttle and debounce in lodash

Tags: javascript, function, lodash

from the lodash documentation:

Throttle

> Creates a throttled function that only invokes func at most once per
>   every wait milliseconds

Debounce

> Creates a debounced function that delays invoking func until after
>   wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last time the debounced
>   function was invoked

I am a little bit confused about these two definitions, it sounds that they are similar.

Can someone give us a simple explanation with examples.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991367/difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing-a-function

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle) link to the article [Debouncing and Throttling Explained Through Examples](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/).

From that article:

> > > The Debounce technique allow us to "group" multiple sequential calls in a single one.

[image: debounce]

> > > By using _.throttle, we don't allow to our function to execute more than once every X milliseconds.
> > >
> > > The main difference between this and debouncing is that throttle guarantees the execution of the function regularly, at least every X milliseconds.

The article explains the differences clearly using prose and diagrams.

Comment: Good stuff, but maybe a bit too verbose. More concise summary and demos can be found in the article "The Difference Between Throttling and Debouncing" (https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/)