# How to use realtime function and debounce both in an event callback?

Tags: javascript

As the title, How can I run realtime function and debounce function in the same callback function such as

```
input.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
  realtimeFn()
  _.debounce(debounceFn, 1000) // how to code here...
})

function realtimeFn () { console.log(1) }


function debounceFn () { console.log(2) }
```

I want to log `1` every time and log `2` after all keyup and 1 second.

Comment: The underscore stands for ???

Comment: @Teemu probably the underscore js

Comment: Yes, lodash or underscore

Comment: @quietcoder which?

Comment: @Teemu I run lodash to test, but both lodash.js and underscore.js is right

Comment: Make sure to be precise, lodash and underscore are not the same thing... Although they are very similar, it's important to understand that they have differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debounce returns a debounced function, you should be using that returned function instead of calling debounce. This code sample should do the thing.

```
var debounced = _.debounce(debounceFn, 1000) ;
input.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
  realtimeFn();
  debounced();
})

function realtimeFn () { console.log(1) }


function debounceFn () { console.log(2) }
```

Comment: Thank you, and it seems that I need to read the source code of lodash.throttle and underscore.throttle.

Comment: Depends on what are your needs exactly. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991367/difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing-a-function

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_win_setTimeout.asp):

```
input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    setInterval("realtimeFn()", 1000);
setTimeout("debounceFn()", 1000);
});
```