# React Native - Show View while Scrolling in Flatlist

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

I need to **SHOW** a view when scroll is started and **HIDE** a view when scroll is stopped.

To detect the scroll movement, there is two ways:

1. Called when the user begins to drag the scroll view.

   ```
   onScrollBeginDrag={this.showView}
   onScrollEndDrag={this.hideView}
   ```
2. Called when the momentum scroll starts and Ends

   ```
   onMomentumScrollBegin={this.showView}
   onMomentumScrollEnd={this.hideView}
   ```

**Exptected Behaviour:**

If continues scroll is happening, it should not hide the view even `onScrollEndDrag` is called and still show the view until `onMomentumScrollEnd`.

If continues scroll is not active, its should hide when `onScrollEndDrag` called

**Actual Behaviour:**

If continues scroll is happening, its hide the view when `onScrollEndDrag` is called and shows the view again until `onMomentumScrollEnd`. So in between view is disappeared and then its appears when drag released.

Comment: I think you only need to use onScrollBeginDrag (to show the view) and onMomentumScrollEnd (to hide the view)

Comment: @dentemm But if onMomentumScrollBegin is not active, its should hide when onScrollEndDrag called.

Comment: Okay, you could also use onScroll() in combination with onScrollEventThrottle and a timer. If onScroll() has not been called for x milliseconds you could hide the view

Comment: Awesome! I called a debounced function in `onScroll`

Comment: Alright glad it works!

Answer (score 1):

Call a debounced function in `onScroll`.

> Debouncing will mean it is called at the end (or start) of a bunch of
>   events. [More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25991510/3694459)

```
// Debounce
this.ViewVisibility = lodash.debounce(this.ViewVisibility, 100);

onScroll={() => {
  this.ViewVisibility();
}}

ViewVisibility = () => {
  console.log('Debouncing');
  this.hideView();
}
```