# Wait for Typing to Stop coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Im looking for a way to wait to pop up the icon until the user is finished done typing. So what I am doing is an ajax call to the serve to check if the user name is registered through our system. If the username is registered it show a Red X, if it's not it shows a Green check mark. The problem is the icons show automatically when the user start typing. I believe its the .on keyup (event) ->

```
ready = ->
  $('#invalid-username').hide()
  $('#valid-username').hide()

  $('#register-username').on 'keyup', (event) ->
    $.ajax
      url: '/username_validator?username=' + $('#register-username').val()
      type: 'POST'
      dataType: 'json'
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        if data.valid is true
          $('#invalid-username').hide()
          $('#valid-username').show()
          console.log('valid')
        else if data.valid is false
          $('#valid-username').hide()
          $('#invalid-username').show()
          console.log('Invalid')
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false
  return false

$(document).ready ready
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ready
```

Comment: What you are looking for is debounce/throttle logic.

Comment: a debounce/throttle logic?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991367/difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing-a-function#25991510

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run javascript function when user finishes typing instead of on key up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220126/run-javascript-function-when-user-finishes-typing-instead-of-on-key-up)