# Lodash debounce firing every change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, lodash

I'm trying to debounce sending a Redux Action from an input change in React.

```
const debouncedSubmit = debounce(() => dispatch(new TaskAnswerSubmit({index: props.index, text: answer})), 1000)

function onChange(e){
    setAnswer(e.target.value)
    debouncedSubmit()
}
```

This is delaying sending the actions, but still sending one for every keypress. I want to wait a second after the typing finishes before sending the action just once.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe what's happening here is that each key press causes a re-render, and during each render it's creating a new `debouncedSubmit` function, and each of those is firing. Try using React's `useCallback` method to memoize the function so it's not recreated on re-renders:

```
const debouncedSubmit = useCallback(debounce(() => dispatch(new TaskAnswerSubmit({index: props.index, text: answer})), 1000), []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to throttle.

This is an answer from a previously asked question about the difference between throttle and debounce [Difference Between throttling and debouncing a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991367/difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing-a-function):

Throttling will delay executing a function. It will reduce the notifications of an event that fires multiple times.

Debouncing will bunch a series of sequential calls to a function into a single call to that function. It ensures that one notification is made for an event that fires multiple times.