# Vuejs throttle search input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am attempting to implement a search and have an input were a user types in a search term and every 1.5 seconds i want it to hit the endpoint to get the search results. Right now I have an input like this

```
<input v-model="term" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"
           v-on:input="search($event.target.value)" @focusin="enableSearch" @focusout="clear">
```

The I have a function that is throttled using lodash throttle method to call the endpoint.

```
search: _.throttle(function (term) {
        if (this.term != null && this.term.length > 3) {
            this.toggleSearch();
            this.searchQueue(term)
        }
    }, 1500),
```

now when i type in a search term like "Joe D" instead of getting one call to the endpoint i get 4. It looks like i get a endpoint call for each key press.

Not sure why the throttling is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tried to [recreate your example](https://codepen.io/genechk/pen/jOrKzdo) and it appears to be working.

Answer (score 2):

You may want [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) instead of [throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle).

Throttle is more about spacing out events per time frame, while debounce is about combining multiple events into one.

Here is a nice [demo](https://web.archive.org/web/20180324022838/http://demo.nimius.net/debounce_throttle/) that illustrates the difference and you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991367/difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing-a-function#:%7E:text=Throttling%20will%20delay%20executing%20a,event%20that%20fires%20multiple%20times.).

Comment: I tried both and instead of getting one call i  am getting 4

Comment: Are you typing slower than the 1.5s debounce rate?  If yes-- that's why.  If no-- you're possibly doing something counterproductive in `searchQueue` or some other method which isn't shown.  Here is a simple [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/2yejmLp8/)

Comment: The throttle method runs once but for some reason my axios call is running multiple times

Comment: Sounds like throttle is completely unrelated to the issue.  Time to add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: Revisiting old questions, I see that you never added `searchQueue` or `toggleSearch` code to see why it's running multiple times.