# Get deltaY from scroll event

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set up a project for use with mobile and desktop but the wheel event doesn't work on mobile, so I need to use scroll.

I know how to get the deltaY from the Wheel event:

```
window.addEventListener("wheel", event => console.info(event.deltaY));
```

How do I get the deltaY from the Scroll event?

Comment: Store the last known Y and subtract it from the Y you get after scrolling to get deltaY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should memorize the last scroll position in a variable, and when the scroll event fires, you can compute the difference.

Here is a modified example for your use case from the MDN docs on [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event):

```js
let lastKnownScrollPosition = 0;
let deltaY = 0;

document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  let ticking = false;
  if (!ticking) {
    // event throtteling
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      deltaY = window.scrollY - lastKnownScrollPosition;
      lastKnownScrollPosition = window.scrollY;
      console.log('deltaY', deltaY);
      ticking = false;
    });
    ticking = true;
  }


});
```

```css
body {
  background: lightgrey;
  height: 8000px;
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

The code above uses throtteling in order to reduce the amount of fired events. Also see: [Difference Between throttling and debouncing a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991367/difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing-a-function)

Comment: Thanks huge help, however in my tests - I see an identical amount of fired events between the original version you posted and the throttled version.

Comment: My code already uses throtteling.

Comment: before you posted the previous code without the throttling. I tried both and tested them both in the same document and try performed identically