# prevent addeventlistener from running again for a certain time

Tags: javascript, scroll, addeventlistener, timing

how to prevent javascript event from running again for a certain time after it's run

Comment: what i need is just the function to prevent the images from changing too fast i took care of the others

Comment: You should look into [throttling/debouncing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991367/difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing-a-function).

Comment: @Andy has found one good duplicate of your question, in your case you're interested in the debounce behavior